# How to expand a tuple in a yield?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, yield

I am trying to expand a tuple in a yield statement but I'm getting a `SyntaxError`. Is this even possible, or is the `*` operator only for function calls?

Here is an example below:

```
class Inner(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._vals = {'a': 1,
                      'b': 2,
                      'c': 3,
                      'd': 4}

    def __iter__(self):
        for key, val in self._vals.items():
            yield key, val

class Outer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._morevals = {"foo": Inner(),
                          "bar": Inner()}

    def __iter__(self):
        for key, moreval in self._morevals.items():
            for val in moreval:
                yield key, *val    # !!! <--- This is where the error is

object_under_test = Outer()

for outer_key, inner_key, inner_value in object_under_test:
    print("{} {} {}".format(outer_key, inner_key, inner_value))

    # Want:
    # foo a 1
    # foo b 2
    # foo c 3
    # foo d 4
    # bar a 1
    # bar b 2
    # bar c 3
    # bar d 4
```

Instead, I'm getting this error:

```
    yield key, *val
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add parentheses, either around the tuple:

```
yield (key, *val)
```

`yield` is special here in that the form only accepts an expression list, not a [`starred_list` form](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists).

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to parenthesize it. In short, use:

```
yield (key, *val)
```

---

Alternatively, you could shorten it by using `yield from` with a comprehension. All in all, your `__iter__` looking like:

```
 def __iter__(self):
    items = self._morevals.items()
    yield from ((k, *v) for k, vals in items for v in vals)
```

Similarly, using `yield from` in `ClassOne.__iter__`:

```
def __iter__(self):
    yield from self._vals.items()
```